# How to get anti forgery token

Tags: c#

Hi i need to test a download link for that i need to login , When i try to log in with the below code i get redirect back to error page since i don't have the anti forgery token , Can you tell me how to get the anti forgery token , I am very new to this thanks in advance

```
//Make a post to LoginTest page
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(loginUrlwith the login credential ) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "HEAD";
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

HttpWebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create(downloadurl) as HttpWebRequest;
request2.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request2.CookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
HttpWebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Depends on how it is implemented on the website you are visiting. If you are visiting a ASP.NET MVC application, it is a hidden field of the form.

Comment: Where does the page get the token from when you log in using a web browser?

Comment: Yes its a Asp.Net MVC application it does store it in hidden field is there any way to get that value